# Associate lead with missed chat transcript

Tags: liveagent, livechattranscript

Set the stage: Custom chat window with prechat form.

In the scenario that a user initiates a Live Chat session but then closes the chat session before an agent accepts the chat, we are finding that a chat transcript is created with status "Missed". As the user closes that chat window, I create a new lead if it doesn't already exist (by capturing the `window.onbeforeunload` event). I would then like to associate that chat transcript with the lead, but I'm not finding a way to do that because I can't find a way to get the chatKey or transcript ID in our custom chat window. Is this even possible?